# How to detect copy and cut actions in visual studio code extensions?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I develop a vscode extension.
I would like to decect user action for copy and cut on the editor.

I checked [API reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api), but I could not find the method.

How can I do this in extensions with typescript ?

Comment: I'd be interested in this one as well. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.documenteventsclass.aspx) is lacking at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no API for that, and by [VSCode Approach to Extensibility](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/patterns-and-principles), you may be out of luck.

I had tried to **replace** the original `Copy` and `Cut` commands, but ended up creating new commands and adding instructions to the user to replace the keybindings, when I created my [Copy Word in Cursor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.copy-word) extension. I had [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6994) because VSCode itself does not publish a `Clipboard` object (compared to Atom), so I had to do myself, using `node-copy-paste` package.

Unless they have changed its idea (try to open an issue on VSCode repo), you should create new `Copy` and `Cut` commands to accomplish what your extension needs to do.

---